# How to get the particular data from versionone through REST API such as the number of opened defect in range time

Tags: versionone

I'm going to collect some data from VersionOne through REST API such as the number opened defects that were submitted in a week..... I try to search but nothing meets my needs. So hope I can have your helps if you faced it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should approach this

1. week period -  This is an begin and end date needed.
2. A Defect has an attribute CreateDate and CreateDateUTC. Use CreateDateUTC.
   count the results of the query
3. Build your query a step at a time.  It is easier to master the API in little pieces.

   a) Query all submitted defects 
     http://YourVersionOneInstance/rest-1.v1/Data/Defects 

   b) Query all Defects that are Open (Active)
     http://YourVersionOneInstance/rest-1.v1/Data/Defects?where=AssetState='64'

   c) Query all Defects that are Open and created between two dates
   http://YourVersionOneInstance/rest-1.v1/Data/Defects?where=AssetState='64'&where=CreateDateUTC>='2017-03-01T12:00:00.000';CreateDateUTC<='2017-03-10T11:59:00.000'

Comment: Thanks everyone :). I found a Python API for VersionOne. Now I get my need.